# C++ letter guessing game

Tags: c++

I'm creating a guessing game with the input being parsed through the command line argument. I've managed to replace all the words with '*'. I have to get input from the user to guess a letter and decrypt the message. I am having problems in terms of replacing the letters back and I have no idea on how to start. Appreciate some assistance from you guys.

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
char letter;
string s(argv[1]);
string s2(argv[2]);
string s3(argv[3]);


  if(argc == 1)
  {
     cout<<"No arguments.You should run this program in terminal with an argument."<<endl;
     exit(1);
  }
   else
   { 
    if (s.find("programming") != string::npos)
    s.replace(s.find("programming"), 11, "***********");
    if (s2.find("is") != string::npos)
    s2.replace(s2.find("is"), 2, "**");
    if (s3.find("awesome") != string::npos)
    s3.replace(s3.find("awesome"), 7, "*******");

    cout<<"Guess a letter in the message: " << s <<" "<< s2 <<" "<< s3 <<endl;
    cout<<"Enter a letter to guess: ";

    cin>>letter;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ? please tell us your problem statement clearly !

Comment: your code is kinda bad because of the variable names, also you should first check if 4 args or more are given.

Comment: One of the most important skills in programming is to be able to break down a problem into smaller, elemental parts.  You need to do this here - you're stuck because you've not taken your eyes off the big picture.  Think about all the steps you'll need to accomplish your goal.  How to take input from a user.  How to store input taken from a user.  How to find a character in a string.  How to copy a string - etc, etc.  List out all the tools you will need - for each one you need help with, make a short, specific question here rather than one vague and overly broad one.

Comment: I like this question, I think this is an interesting problem. But most people on here aren't interested in your program so they will refuse to help you. I will help you when i get to a computer. currently on phone

Comment: Another hint: you can't just 'throw away' the original to-be guessed word.  Which means you need to keep 2 things for each word: the original word itself and a string containing asterisks for all non-guessed characters.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit - the answers don't make sense if you remove the question.  Better for you to [edit] the question to focus on a specific part of the problem - the most immediate next step that is preventing you from moving forward.

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't call your program with the right number of arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I'll try to help you somehow...

First. you launch program assuming, that you passed 3 strings as an argument to the program and you are assigning it to the `std::string` variables. Then you are checking, wheather you passed those 3 arguments.

That is wrong. What if you do not pass 3 arguments and launch a program? What will be held in argv[1] argv[2] and argv[3]? Some rubbish nothing more and if you are lucky enough your program won't crash. You should first check wheather you passed arguments and if so then make any assignments associated with them. Otherwise you are assigning rubbish to `s`, `s2` and `s3`

If you want to continously check for input arguments. You should use do...while() loop. I won't describe it here as it can be found anywhere on the Internet. Everytime you simply check if given letter is in any of the strings `"programming"`, `"is"`, `"awesome"` and then replace your **** on correct position with a given letter if letter is found. You should do this while(any of the strings has a letter '*' in it).

That's how I would describe the problem, but I won't write this for you. It's best to learn, when you programm.

I would ask you to make more effort before asking on this forum. you should at least try to use any while loop to accomplish your task and not give this to us. Hovewer I understand, that someone has to start somewhere and beginnings are not easy. Good luck!